# Можно ли в Visual Studio отследить возникающие события?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Работаю с формой в дебаге. Хотелось бы знать, какие события генерируются при том или ином моем действии. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Насколько знаю, единственный способ отследить возникшее событие - это подписаться на него.

Comment: @SoulMicro, а если я не знаю, на что мне подписываться?

Comment: @iRumba Winforms или WPF? для Winforms есть рабочий способ :)

Comment: @iRumba, можно предположить какие события из списка событий могут быть спровоцированы теми или иными действиями и подписаться на всех их.

Comment: @SoulMicro вопрос как раз в том, чтобы не предполагать, а узнать точно, насколько я понял

Comment: @PashaPash, правильно поняли. Надо для WPF

Comment: @PashaPash, все верно. В процессе разработки вы предполагаете какие именно события могут быть спровоцированы действием и подписываетесь на них. Далее запускаете на отладку и выполняете ключевое действие. По точкам останова вы точно определите какие события будут спровоцированы и в каком порядке. Далее отписываетесь от ненужных событий и пишете код в том, которое вам наиболее подходит.

Comment: @SoulMicro, мне проще через foreach и reflection подписаться на все события нужного контрола и сделать вывод в консоль с названием события. Но вопрос тут не о программировании а о возможностях среды

Comment: @SoulMicro да, это отлично - но вот вопрос как раз в том "как узнать точно, а не предполагать". И нет, подписаться на событие - не единственный способ узнать, было ли событие вызвано - есть же еще отладчик, и вопрос именно по использованию его возможностей

Comment: @iRumba я напишу ответ про WinForms + часть событий в WFP (раз уж вопрос действительно про возможности среды), дополню как только найду вторую половину для WPF.

Comment: @PashaPash, ага. Но у меня рабочий день закончен, прочитаю уже завтра

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть способ, основанный на внутренней организации стандартных событий. Он применим для перехвата обычных (не-routed) событий - почти всех событий в WinForms, и части событий в WPF:

Т.к. событий много (десятки-сотни в каждом контроле) - backing-поля для стандартной реализации событий занимали бы много памяти, даже в случае если на события никто не подписан. Поэтому в классе базовых классах типа [Control](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,befabd4e80628cae) или [Window](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,f5b9361149b7f7c4) есть общий для всех событий список обработчиков:

```
protected EventHandlerList Events {
    get {
        if (events == null) {
            events = new EventHandlerList(this);
        }
        return events;
    }
}
```

и обычная реализация события выглядит вот так:

```
private static readonly object EventSize = new object();

public event EventHandler SizeChanged {
    add {
        Events.AddHandler(EventSize, value);
    }
    remove {
        Events.RemoveHandler(EventSize, value);
    }
}

protected virtual void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
    EventHandler eh = Events[EventSize] as EventHandler;
    if (eh != null) {
        eh(this,e);
    }
}
```

Так что для трассировки таких событий достаточно

- снять Debug \ Options \ Enable Just My Code
- запустить отладку
- создать новый Debug \ New Breakpoint \ Function Breakpoint

В качестве имени функции ввести индексатор EventHandlerList

```
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList.get_Item
```

В качестве действия - печать `$CALLER` и продолжение выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убедится, что трейспойнт поставился - он должен быть заполненным красным ромбом в окне Breakpoints. После этого все события будут выведены в окно Output, включая те, на которые никто не подписан.

Для Routed Events в WPF есть встроенная трассировка. Теоретически ее можно просто включить в Debug \ Options \ Output Window \ WPF Trace Settings, но у меня эта опция по какой-то странной причине не заработала.

Включение из кода выглядит так:

```
PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener());
PresentationTraceSources.RoutedEventSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All;
```

После этого WPF начнет массово спамить в Output о всех происходящий событиях.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! )